# Como uso uma constante dentro de um método de uma classe?

Tags: php, classes, constantes

Defini uma constante em um arquivo e gostaria de chamá-la dentro de um método em uma classe.
Exemplo:

Arquivo: `Configuracao.php`

```
<?php
define('FOO','Hello World');
require_once('Classe.php');
?>
```

Arquivo: `Classe.php`

```
<?php
namespace testeConstant;

Class Foo {
    public function exibeFoo(){
        echo FOO;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Percebeu que sua constante se chama `FOO`, mas você está tentando usar como `Foo`?

Comment: A aspa invertida no final do `define` é um erro de digitação?

Comment: Provável, assim como os asteriscos duplos dentro do bloco de código.

Comment: Na realidade eu coloquei os asteriscos duplos para visualizar melhor onde eu queria imprimir a constante e o 'Foo' com letra minúscula foi falta de atenção minha na hora de digitar

Comment: Tudo bem, mas e então, resolveu? Se sim, marque a resposta que te ajudou como resolvida. Sua dúvida hoje poderá ser a de outro amanhã. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente, para usar sua constante na aplicação basta fazer isso:

```
<?php

echo FOO;
```

Isso funciona porque o `define` mantém as constantes no escopo global da aplicação.

No caso de sua classe, repare que ela usa um `namespace`, logo ao declarar `FOO` na verdade você está tentando chamar `testeConstant::FOO`, que não existe.

Para contornar esse problema, você precisa adicionar um `\` para referenciar ao escopo global dentro da sua classe com `namespace`.

```
<?php

namespace testeConstant;

include_once("Configuracao.php");

Class Foo {
    public function exibeFoo(){
        echo \FOO; // Hello World
    }
}
```

Outras considerações importantes:

- O `namespace` deve ser a primeira coisa no seu arquivo depois do `<?php`
- `Constants` são case-sensitive, ou seja, `Foo` é diferente de `FOO`
- Se o seu arquivo só tiver códigos PHP, pode omitir a tag de fechamento `?>`

Comment: Depende da posição do include, certo? O que, aliás, a pergunta não mostra.

Comment: @bfavaretto o include pode estar em um arquivo diferente. O que não pode ocorrer é ter qualquer coisa antes do namespace

Comment: @bfavaretto uma [forma diferente de fazer](https://gist.github.com/gmsantosxl/edb94ae700792dc8175c) (acredito que pode ser assim que o OP esteja fazendo)

Comment: Também acho que é isso que ele está fazendo, mas não tem como termos certeza.

Comment: Então. o include da classe esta na ultima linha do arquivo Configuracao.php, Irei corrigir.

Answer (score 3):

Constantes, além de imutáveis são globais, ou seja, contanto que o recurso que dependa dela seja executado depois de sua definição e esteja disponível (ver abaixo), basta chamar por ela.

Porém, o mais importante é que, apesar de seu escopo global, como tudo que se resume ao fluxo da Requisição, caso o arquivo onde essa constante foi definida **não tenha sido incluído** na rotina responsável pela Requisição corrente, ela, a constante, assim como qualquer outro recurso (variáveis, funções, classes...) obviamente não existirá.

Existe, também, a questão dos *namespaces*, levantada enquanto em escrevia essa resposta.

Constantes somente são definidas no contexto de um *namespace* se este for **explicitamente** definido no nome da constante. Ex:

```
<?php

namespace test;

define( 'FOO', 'BAR' );
define( 'test\NAMESPACED_CONSTANT', 'BAAZ' );
```

Esse fragmento de código criará duas constantes, mas apenas a segunda estará restrita ao escopo do *namespace* **test**. Tanto é verdade que esse teste:

```
var_dump( FOO, NAMESPACED_CONSTANT, test\NAMESPACED_CONSTANT );
```

Considerando que os alertas de erros estejam ativados e num nível suficiente para exibir um **Notice**, Vai exibir um aviso por assumir **NAMESPACED_CONSTANT** como sendo uma string, já que esta não pôde ser localizada em meio as [constantes definidas](http://www.php.net/get_deined_constants).

---

Agora, apenas como complemento ao assunto...

Existem ainda as [Constantes de Classe](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.constants.php) que funcionam *quase* da mesma forma que uma constante regular, a diferença é que elas **não têm** escopo global, ficando restritas apenas à classe (não ao objeto) que a(s) definiu(ram).

Além disso, ao invés da função [define()](http://www.php.net/define), constantes de classe são definidas através da palavra-chave **const**, especial dentro de uma classe.

E para acessá-las, usam-se os pseudo-operadores **self::** ou **parent::**, dependendo se esta foi definida na própria classe que a invocou ou em uma superclasse, respectivamente. Caso fora do escopo de uma classe, usa-se o próprio nome da classe definidora, respeitando-se quaisquer *namespaces* declarados:

```
class Foo {

    const BAR = 'Baaz';
}

class MyClass {

    public function __construct() {

        echo Foo::BAR;
    }
}

echo Foo::BAR; // Baaz
echo new MyClass; // Baaz
```

Por fim, apesar do nome, Constantes de Classe não estão restritas a classes. Estas podem ser definidas também em interfaces o que amplia as possibilidade de tipagem oferecidas por uma interface.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
<?php
include_once("Configuracao.php");

Class Foo {
    public function exibeFoo(){
        echo FOO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ou seja, basta usar o mesmo nome definido para a constante no outro arquivo. O que não pode é usar outro nome (e maiúsculas/minúsculas fazem diferença).

Comment: Além de maiúsculos e minúsculos, interessante mencionar o escopo. A classe do OP está em namespace.